# how to split a string in clojure not in regular expression mode

Tags: clojure

The split in both clojure and java takes regular expression as parameter to split. But I just want to use normal char to split. The char passed in could be "|", ","," " etc. how to split a line by that char?

I need some function like (split string a-char). And this function will be called at very high frequency, so need good performance. Any good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your character a regex by properly escaping special characters and use the default regex split (which is fastest by far).

This version will make a regexp that automatically escapes every character or string within it

```
(defn char-to-regex
  [c]
  (re-pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote (str c))))
```

This version will make a regexp that escapes a single character if it's within the special character range of regexps

```
(defn char-to-regex
  [c]
  (if ((set "<([{\\^-=$!|]})?*+.>") c)
    (re-pattern (str "\\" c))
    (re-pattern c)))
```

Make sure to bind the regex, so you don't call `char-to-regex` over and over again if you need to do multiple splits

```
(let [break (char-to-regex \|)]
  (clojure.string/split "This is | the string | to | split" break))
=> ["This is " " the string " " to " " split"]
```

Comment: (Pattern/quote s) is more reliable than (str "\\Q" c "\\E")

Comment: verified re: perf, I made a relatively low level character scanning / splitting version in clojure, but it was 10x slower than a regex split.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few features in `java.util.regex.Pattern` class that support treating strings as literal regular expressions. This is useful for cases such as these. @cgrand already alluded to `(Pattern/quote s)` in a comment to another answer. One more such feature is the `LITERAL` flag ([documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL)). It can be used when compiling literal regular expression patterns. Remember that `#"foo"` in Clojure is essentially syntax sugar for (Pattern/compile "foo"). Putting it all together we have:

```
(import 'java.util.regex.Pattern)
(clojure.string/split "foo[]bar" (Pattern/compile "[]" Pattern/LITERAL))
;; ["foo" "bar"]
```